# Ones removed. Not evident as to why?

Tags: python

Im trying to learn how to code and i think ive almost got it but it seems that some "1's" get removed and i cant seem to figure out why. Can anybody help?

```
test_data = ["1912", "1929", "1913-1923",
             "(1951)", "1994", "1934",
             "c. 1915", "1995", "c. 1912",
             "(1988)", "2002", "1957-1959",
             "c. 1955.", "c. 1970's", 
             "C. 1990-1999"]

bad_chars = ["(",")","c","C",".","s","'", " "]
def strip_characters(test_data):
    for char in bad_chars:
         test_data = test_data.replace(char,"")
         return test_data

stripped_test_data = []
for bad_chars in test_data:
    date = strip_characters(bad_chars)
    stripped_test_data.append(date)
```

This is the result that comes from it:

```
['92',
 '929',
 '93-923',
 '1951)',
 '994',
 '934',
 '. 1915',
 '995',
 '. 1912',
 '1988)',
 '00',
 '957-959',
 '. 1955.',
 ". 1970's",
 '. 1990-1999']
```

All these years are supposed to be in the 1900s but it seems to be taking out some of the ones.

Comment: Well don't use the same variable for two completely different things.

Comment: Use a debugger and debug your code step-by-step. Hint: you are reusing the name `bad_chars`

Comment: @DeepSpace but if i change the bad_chars variable it just does nothing and leaves it the way it is. Thats why im confused

Comment: You also have a misplaced return statement fixed by mrnobody33 in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is said in the comments you are reusing the name `bad_chars`, so change that name in the second loop. Also, in the function you are returning only the first iteration of the loop, because the return it´s inside the loop, so, make the return after the loop:

```
test_data = ["1912", "1929", "1913-1923",
             "(1951)", "1994", "1934",
             "c. 1915", "1995", "c. 1912",
             "(1988)", "2002", "1957-1959",
             "c. 1955.", "c. 1970's", 
             "C. 1990-1999"]

bad_chars = ["(",")","c","C",".","s","'", " "]
def strip_characters(test_data):
    for char in bad_chars:
        test_data = test_data.replace(char,"")
    return test_data                             #<----change: return after the loop

stripped_test_data = []
for a in test_data:                              #<----change: variable name(a instead of bad_chars)          
    date = strip_characters(a)
    stripped_test_data.append(date)
stripped_test_data
```

Output:

```
['1912',
 '1929',
 '1913-1923',
 '1951',
 '1994',
 '1934',
 '1915',
 '1995',
 '1912',
 '1988',
 '2002',
 '1957-1959',
 '1955',
 '1970',
 '1990-1999']
```

Comment: OHH that's what my problem was, i initially didnt have bad_chars in the second loop it was my indentation of my return that was causing the problem. Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome! Please conside [accepting the asnwer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it was helpful ;) @AlertedPanic9